# jQuery cookie gets immediately unset - but only the first time it's set

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

Why might the below only work after the first time? A null cookie is all there is after clicking on a menu item, but every time after that it works perfectly...

I'm using the jquery cookies plugin.

```
$j(document).ready(function(){

$j('#menu-main-nav-menu li').each(function(index) {
    $j(this).data('sc-menu-item', index);
    })

currentPage = $j.cookie('currentPage');
        // do some stuff with the cookie value here

$j('#menu-main-nav-menu li').click(function() {
    $j.cookie('currentPage', $j(this).data('sc-menu-item'))
});

});
```

Thanks very very much for any help - i'm stuck!

Comment: print this value ,before you set cookie , use console.log($j(this).data('sc-menu-item'));

Comment: OK - I figured it out. human error. js was fine, but my domain was redirecting, which resulted in the cookie being set in the wrong domain to begin with. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the js was fine. I set the cookie in the wrong domain... novice that i am...

Answer (score 0):

nashe ,

I don't think there is anything wrong with the cookie plugin , do the following ways to debug

print the value before it sets

```
use console.log($j(this).data('sc-menu-item')); or alert//
```

that value might be null..

the abovedebuging should fix the problem

Comment: thanks Kobe. Unfortunately this gives the correct response! ie the menu-item data _is_ being correctly read and then correctly set in the cookie - it's just being unset when the next page loads. taking this further, i alert()ed the cookie value immediately after this (it was set) and also immediately before (document).ready - by the time that fired on the next page, it was already null.

Answer (score 0):

put an `event.preventDefault()` into the link click event, then setting the cookie, and then forward onwards with the link and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: As it should, but did it set the cookie? If it did, then it is working as intended and you can make the link function again by doing a javascript redirect.

Comment: ah, i see what you mean by 'forward onwards'. I've now tried this -  it does indeed set the cookie properly (as was happening in the first place - see my answer to Kobe, above). However, it's still unset on the page load.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/niklasvh/tJrGa/show/light/ it is at least set for me, even after the page is loaded.

Comment: that does seem to work, thanks for whipping it up. I guess there must be some external influence , but i don't know what that might be?